# Convert dot notation string to array notation string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a dot notation string.

```
let str = 'category.1.subcategory.2.name';
```

Are there any suggestions on how to convert it to an array notation string?

```
convert(str); //desired outcome => 'category[1][subcategory][2][name]'
```

Comment: Split the string at `.`, wrap each element of the resulting array (except the first) with `[]`, then join it back together.

Comment: @Barmar was not my intention to use as a "free coding service". Thanks for the guidance. Will compose question better next time ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let str = 'category.1.subcategory.2.name'
var parts = str.split(".")
var stra = parts[0] + parts.slice(1).map(p => `[${p}]`).join("")
console.log(stra)
```